# How to link components using routes in NextJS?

Tags: next.js

I have all my components in ./src/components folder and want to link components on onclick event of a button. In ReactJS,  the issue is resolved using browserRoutes but how can we do this in NEXTJS?

Tried using this but this is giving 404 error.

```
     <button type="button" className="btn">
        <Link href="/dashboard">Login</Link>
     </button>
```

Dashboard components is present in components folder. Can we resolve the issue by moving all components to ../src/pages folder or we can perform routing in existing structure as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have `/pages/dashboard.tsx(or js)`.

**Next.js** route works with files in `/pages` directory. Check this out: [**Nextjs Docs**](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages).

Comment: thank you...issue resolved.
one more question I want to ask that how can we render components onto the same page without routing. like there is no change in url but when we clicked on some buttton then some other component will render on the same page?